# selecting multiple key with condition in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary containing thousands of key here is an example of it.

```
Mydict = {'A01': 'value1', 'A02': 'value1', 'C01': 'value1', 'C02': 'value1', 
          'D02': 'value1', 'D03': 'value1', 'D04': 'value1', 'D05': 'value1', 
          'D06': 'value1', 'D07': 'value1', 'D08': 'value1', 'D09': 'value1'}
```

I want to creat sub-dictionaries out of based on condition. I want to creat a dictionary that start with specific letter up to. let's say I want 'C' and 'D' but up to 'D08' .  here is the code I wrote. it'll select all C and D.

```
NewDict= {x: Mydict[x] for x in Mydict.keys() if x.__contains__('C' or 'D')}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `'C' or 'D'` evals to 'C', henceforth what you wrote is equivalent to look only for 'C'. You just have to separate your test in two expressions. Also using `in` will be more idiomatic than using `__contains__`

`{x: Mydict[x] for x in Mydict.keys() if 'C' in x or 'D' in x}`

If you want to apply a test on every keys in a list, like check is it's smaller than 'D08', just do that and use lexicographic order.

`NewDict= {x: Mydict[x] for x in Mydict.keys() if x < 'D08'}`

For comparizons of interval python provides a shortcut avoiding to write two expressions and you can directly write:

`NewDict= {x: Mydict[x] for x in Mydict.keys() if 'C01' < x < 'D08'}`

Use inclusive `<=`or exclusive `<` comparizon operator depending on what you want.

For more complicated conditions on keys, it's probably clearer to use an explicit function like:

```
def condition(key):
    return 'C01' < key < 'D08'

NewDict= {x: Mydict[x] for x in Mydict.keys() if condition(x)}
```

With such format you can make your test on key as complicated as you want and the result will remains easy to read.

It would also be more idiomatic and shorter to use `items()` to iterate both on keys and values like:

```
NewDict= {k: v for k,v in Mydict.items() if 'C01' < k < 'D08'}
```

As a last word Camel case variables are usually reserved for classes in python. For variables the common convention would be to use snake case, like `new_dict`.

Comment: that's true, I didn't write my question completely. but here is the correct format. NewDict= {x: Mydict [x] for x in Mydict.keys() if x.__contains__('C')  or x.__contains__( 'D’)}. I want to selet let say up to 'D08'.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to at least need an update:

```
Mydict = {'A01': 'value1', 'A02': 'value1', 'C01': 'value1', 'C02': 'value1', 
          'D02': 'value1', 'D03': 'value1', 'D04': 'value1', 'D05': 'value1', 
          'D06': 'value1', 'D07': 'value1', 'D08': 'value1', 'D09': 'value1'}
NewDict= {x: Mydict[x] for x in Mydict.keys() if x.__contains__('D')
         }
NewDict.update({x: Mydict[x] for x in Mydict.keys() if x.__contains__('C')
         })
NewDict
```

There's probably a more efficient way to do this, however...

Also Python variable names should be in snake case e.g. `new_dict`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `set` for the letters that you want to keep and another for the "ranges". Then you create your dictionary by examining the key appropriately:

```
ranges = set(range(9))
letters = {'C', 'D'}

NewDict = {x: Mydict[x] for x in Mydict if x[0] in letters and int(x[1:]) in ranges}
```

Since checking membership in a `set` is *O(1)* you shouldn't have a problem with performance even if you have thousands of keys.

If you want to get really detailed about your keys and ranges, you can create a dictionary specifying which ranges you want for each key. For example:

```
ranges = {
    'C': set(), # empty set denotes select all 'C'
    'D': set(range(9))
}

NewDict = {x: Mydict[x] for x in Mydict if x[0] in ranges and (len(ranges[x[0]]) == 0 or int(x[1:]) in ranges[x[0]])}

print(NewDict)
```

**Output**

```
{'C01': 'value1', 'C02': 'value1', 'D02': 'value1', 'D03': 'value1', 'D04': 'value1', 'D05': 'value1', 'D06': 'value1', 'D07': 'value1', 'D08': 'value1'}
```